# Change ngx-uploader UploadInput data in multiple upload

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-uploader

Here is my code to start upload multiple files using ngx-uploader:

```
startUpload(): void {
  let token = this.myToken;  // <----  get token
  const event: UploadInput = {
    type: 'uploadAll',
    url: 'http://ngx-uploader.com/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'JWT ' + token },  // <----  set headers
    data: { 
        conversation_id: this.conversation.id,
        message_id: this.message_id }
  };

  this.uploadInput.emit(event);
}
```

In the first request, data.message_id is null and server will generate a new id.

After that I will get the new id in the response and update to data.message_id. But there is no way to update message_id for the next request.

Comment: So you want to use/update the same new id (which is generated by server) for your next request also?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the same new id for all next request. Current, all request alway send a null id.